# Can I efficiently swap two class instances by swapping __dict__?

Tags: python

I have a big class with lots of members, and quite a few references to instances of this class lying around. Unfortunately (for reasonable reasons) all these references are the wrong way around.

Instead of re-creating each (and finding and updating everywhere the objects are referenced), or adding an extra level of indirection each time I access this class, or individually swapping members, I have defined a method:

```
def swap(self, other):
    assert(isinstance(other, self.__class__))
    self.__dict__, other.__dict__ = other.__dict__, self.__dict__
```

so I can do:

```
instance_a.swap(instance_b)
# now all references to instance_a everywhere are as if instance_a is instance_b
```

**The question:**
It seems to work fine (I don't use `__slots__`), but it feels like there might be a reason I shouldn't do this, is there?

---

Here's my actual use case:

I have a type that implements comparison operators in a (necessarily) expensive way. I have various sorted data-structures containing objects of this type.

When I do something to one of the objects, I know that the comparison order has changed, and that order in my data structures (all of them!) can be restored by swapping the modified object with the 'next bigger' one.

Comment: Pythonic way of swapping variables: `self.__dict__, other.__dict__ = other.__dict__, self.__dict__`.

Comment: This seems to be bound to create headaches and subtle bugs.

Comment: You are using the term "class" when you really mean "object" or "instance".

Comment: You _can_ do it, but one can only wonder how you have gotten into this mess

Comment: I would set up a macro instead to swap all the names round. You'll save yourself ( and those who follow you ) many many headaches.

Comment: @Ben: macro? what language do yout think the question is about?

Comment: @Ferdinand, sorry; clarified!

Comment: @utdemir, neat; I've updated the question.

Comment: @jsbueno I assume that Autopulated is using a text editor of some description to edit his code. Even if he's not it's about 10 lines of python to search a directory tree and do the necessary replacements.

Comment: @Ben: I've added my actual use case and sorted out my wording again.

Comment: @gnibbler; I've added a particular use-case.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this is a pretty nice implementation of swap. I don't find it hackish. I'd make it a free function `swap(lhs, rhs)`, instead of a class function, but that's another point.

Comment: @Autopulated: seems to me that the only reason you shouldn't do this is "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEKKKKK!" Technically, I think it should be fine, but in concurrence with what others have said, it makes me cringe.

Comment: If the instances are of the same class, if they are mutable (i.e. they don't define the __hash__ method), it should be probably reasonable safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are actually swapping instances of a class, not classes.

Instance state is kept in two possible places:  `__slots__` and `__dict__`.  If you swap those, you've basically swapped instances while retaining the original name bindings.  One caveat is that the class *cannot* be immutable (must not define `__hash__()`) as any instances that were already members of a set or keys in a dictionary would then become irretrievable.

If it were me, I think I would have the .swap() method be a class method instead -- I think it would read easier:

```
class SomeBigClass():
    @staticmethod
    def swap_dict(instance_a, instance_b):
        instance_a.__dict__, instance_b.__dict__ = \
                instance_b.__dict__, instance_a.__dict__
    @classmethod
    def swap_slot(cls, instance_a, instance_b):
        values = []
        for attr in cls.__slots__:
            values.append(
                (attr,
                 getattr(instance_a, attr),
                 getattr(instance_b, attr),
                 ))
        for attr, val1, val2 in values:
            setattr(instance_a, attr, val2)
            setattr(instance_b, attr, val1)
```

and then later

```
SomeBigClass.swap_dict(this_instance, other_instance)
```

or

```
SomeBigClass.swap_slot(this_instance, other_instance)
```

Why shouldn't you do this?  If you have instances bound to names you should not do this.  Consider:

```
frubbah = SomeBigClass(attr="Hi, Mom!")
zikroid = SomeBigClass(attr='Hi, Dad!")
SomeBigClass.swap_dict(frubbah, zikroid)
```

After the swap, potentially everything you thought you knew about zikroid has changed.

Comment: Note that `__slots__` is merely the class-wide list of attributes that are supported on that class's instances; each instances does *not* get its *own* `__slots__` that could be swapped with that of another instance. Nor would it help, since `__slots__` is just the variable names — like `['a','b']` — and does not include the actual values. But, as your answer notes, you *can* do tricks with `__dict__` because it is per-instance and not per-class.

Comment: @Brandon: Very good point, thank you.  Updated code to show how to handle `__slots__`.

Comment: How would you do it to swap to objects, instances of different classes?

Answer (score 9):

### Edit

What you're doing is possible, although it will make people cringe because it is hackish. If at all possible, I would suggest that you look at rewriting/refactoring your comparison operators. That will give you the best outcome by far. Of course, not knowing the scope or time-frame involved, it is very difficult to tell whether this is immediately practical, but trust me, you will spend less time re-writing in the long term if you can do things "right".

### Original

Realistically, it sounds like you're dealing with three classes -- a data object and two utility classes -- but that is another issue.

This will break, so I am going to go ahead and say, "no, you cannot swap classes by swapping `__dict__`s":

```
>>> class Foo:
...    def __init__(self):
...        self.__bar = 1
...    def printBar(self):
...        print self.__bar
... 
>>> class Bar:
...    def __init__(self):
...        self.__bar=2
...    def printBar(self):
...        print self.__bar
... 
>>> f=Foo()
>>> f.printBar() # works as expected
1
>>> f=Foo()
>>> b=Bar()
>>> f.__dict__, b.__dict__ = b.__dict__, f.__dict__
>>> f.printBar() # attempts to access private value from another class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in printBar
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute '_Foo__bar'
```

Comment: Sorry, my wording was pretty poor re: classes vs. objects. I only have one type, and two instances of the same type. I've updated the wording in the question to try to be more precise!

Comment: I've also added a use-case to try to clarify why I want to do this.

Comment: Also, identity will be broken.

Answer (score 1):

This swapping should be implemented in your sorted data structures, not in this class for its instances.

Comment: The datastructure doesn't know when I modify one of the items though, so at best I'd have to remove, and re-insert with a position hint. Since comparison is *very* expensive, and I know exactly what needs changing already, I think it's best if I do it behind the sorted datastructure's back.

Answer (score 0):

For your own sanity, and that of whoever may use your code after you, if you decide to use this function, you should document the hell out of it so that you know what's going on.  Your more self-documenting alternative, of course, is to write a function that swaps all the data members individually.  Obviously this isn't very future-proof if your data model will be changing, but it will be less confusing.  If it's not something you want to write out by hand, you could define a function to swap one data field, and run it over all your class attributes:

```
def swap (a, b):
  for key in a.__dict__.keys():
    swapOneField(key, a, b)
```

and for `swapOneField` get the values from `a.__dict__` and `b.__dict__` and use the swapping algorithm of your choice.  It's more verbose, and probably less efficient, but if you save more time in not debugging it than you lose in running it, it's probably worth your time.