# How to exchange 2 objects' identities in python?

Tags: python, object, identity, memory-address

I have 2 instances `x` and `y` of a same class `RBnode`.
Is there a way to exchange their identities so that all reference to `x` goes to `y` and vice versa?

For example,

```
x = RBnode()
y = RBnode()
x.data = 1
y.data = 2
L = [x,y]

exchange_identity(x,y)
print x.data, y.data, (L[0] is y)

>>> 2 1 True
```

Actually I'm building an extension of Red-Black tree. Nodes of the tree are implemented as object. When writing the node removal method, I need to exchange two nodes, so that the node to be removed gets "at the bottom" of the tree.

First I tried to just exchange data in the two nodes:

```
def remove_node(self, y):
    ''' remove node y from tree
    return (y.key,y.value) if successful'''
... ... ...

    # exchange y's data with that of its successor y.next 

    y.key = y.next.key
    y.value = y.next.value
```

But later an error occurred when `remove_node` was called and the caller function was holding a reference to a node `x`, which happens to be `y.next`. Something like

```
x = y.next
self.remove_node(y)
x.parent
>>> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

I could exchange all corresponding attributes of `x` and `y`.
But that takes pretty many lines since the structure of a node is rather complicated.

Comment: You might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255777/can-i-efficiently-swap-two-class-instances-by-swapping-dict (but there be dragons.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I must be missing something, because what's wrong with this?

```
>>> class RBnode(object):
...   pass
... 
>>> x = RBnode()
>>> y = RBnode()
>>> id(x), id(y)
(20552592, 20552528)
>>> x,y = y,x
>>> id(x), id(y)
(20552528, 20552592)
```

Or have you meant for reassigning *all* the names, like some kind of identity theft of an object?  While it would be possible working at the C level, I would be pretty surprised if you could do it from within python without breaking things majorly.

Comment: I want to do something like exchanging the memory address of the two objects, I think it's what you call 'identity theft'. I'm just curious if that is possible within Python. Thank you!

Comment: You can exchange the contents of the objects as you're doing, or you can realize that there aren't really that many references to reassign and just swap the nodes' locations in the tree, or you can add a level of indirection.

Answer (score 1):

"Identity theft" isn't possible in Python; however, you can usually exchange the *contents* of two different objects (and perhaps even exchange the *type* for user defined classes):

```
>>> n = Node()
>>> o = Node()
>>> p = Node(n, o)
>>> q = Node()
>>> r = Node(p, q)

>>> # swap bodies of p and r
>>> p.left, p.right, r.left, r.right = p.right, p.left, r.right, r.left
```