# Swap two instances of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, instance, swap

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import chess.uci
import chess
import chess.pgn
import chess.svg

def set_engine(engine_path):
    engine = chess.uci.popen_engine(engine_path)
    engine.uci()
    engine.ucinewgame()
    return engine

def chess_match(engine1,engine2):
    while not board.is_game_over():
        engine1.position(board)
        engine1_move,ponder= engine1.go(movetime=100)
        board.push(engine1_move)
        engine2.position(board)
        engine2_move,ponder= engine2.go(movetime=100)
        board.push(engine2_move)

    print(engine1.name ," - ", engine2.name, board.result())


board = chess.Board()
start = board.set_fen(chess.STARTING_FEN)

engine1 = set_engine(".../Chess Engines/andscacs.exe")
engine2 = set_engine(".../Chess Engines/stockfish_18102108_x64_modern.exe")

for _ in range(6):
    chess_match(engine1,engine2)
    engine1, engine2 = engine2, engine1
```

In the above code, I am writing program to conduct match between chess engine using `python-chess` module. In this line of code

```
for _ in range(6):
    chess_match(engine1,engine2)
    engine1, engine2 = engine2, engine1
```

I want to do 6 match between the engines and they will switch sides every game. `engine1` and `engine2` are instances of `chess.uci.Engine` class. After I tried the code, the result is the same every time meaning the engine did not switch sides. After some browsing, I realize that you cannot swap two instances of a class by tuple unpacking. I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255777/can-i-efficiently-swap-two-class-instances-by-swapping-dict) about the same problem but still cannot figure how to write the swap method. I am using Python 3.6 in Windows 10.

Comment: What is the output you get from `print(engine1.name ," - ", engine2.name, board.result())`?

Comment: There's too much unrelated code in your question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Shouldn't you reset the board before each game?

Comment: Swapping seems to be fine as it stands

Comment: For every match after the first one, `board.is_game_over()` will immediately return true, so `chess_match()` doesn't actually do anything but print the results.  You'll need to reset the board and engine state between each match.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly solution you're asking for, but what about adding another bool variable to determine which engine should start?

```
swap = False
for _ in range(6):
    chess_match(swap and engine2 or engine1, swap and engine1 or engine2)
    swap = not swap
```